# Calculating range of between LED and phototransistor

Tags: led, phototransistor

[image]

I would like to tell briefly about circuit. When LED is ligth(on),it will trigger ptohotransistor for work. I wonder that between these two component of range is important. Is there any calculate metod for unknown range ? How can I design productive this circuit ? How many length should be between LED and Phototransistor ?

Comment: This depends on the properties of the LED and the PT. And without the datasheets, we cannot say anything.

Comment: @CL. Do datasheets have this properties. I didn't see anywhere.

Comment: @CL. Which parameter should I look in datasheet ?

Comment: Given the drawing, it seems both LED and PT are located in a closed device, aren't they? And they will be relatively close to each other, not more than a few centimeters apart, won't they? So you don't have to worry. Think about a remote control. They don't use particularily powerful LED and particularily sensitive sensor, but they can see each other a few meters apart. The fact it's IR doesn't change things much.

Comment: The easy way to avoid engineering this yourself is to just buy an integrated *optointerruptor* device.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for your advice. I will evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LED emits light power. That light power is projected across a spherical arc (maybe 60 degrees) and the power density (watts per square metre) reduces with the square of distance from the LED.

The photo transistor has an active surface area and a conversion factor of incident watts to collector current. So, work backwards: -

- What collector current do you need?
- What incident light power is required for this current?
- How many watts per square metre is that equivalent to?
- What distance does the LED have to be from the photo-transistor to produce this power density.

If your data sheets don't tell you these figures find devices that do. Also make sure that the peak sensitivity of the transistor matches the colour of light produced or you will have less distance.

Answer (score 1):

- The thing is that every LED has a certain directivity and a certain luminous intensity.
- The PT has an acceptance angle and a sensitivity.

Without those two parameters you can't tell about the function.